# Python AJAX not working PHP webpage

Tags: javascript, php, python, ajax

I am trying to make a website which when a certain button is pressed, a python script will run, which will turn on GPIO pins on my raspberry pi.

However my code doesn't seem to work. Please could someone tell me what is wrong with my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#clickON').click(function(){
                var a = new XMLHttpRequest():
                a.open("GET","output.py")
                a.onreadystatechange=function(){
                    if(a.readySate==4){
                        if(a.status == 200){
                        }
                        else alert("HTTP ERROR!!")
                    }PHP
                }
                a.send
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button type="button" id="clickON">ON</button><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: learn to do basic debuggin, e.g. pop open your JS debug console, and you'd see `a.readySate`.... readyState, perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging Javascript can be done through your browser's developer tools. In Chrome for OSX, I access them by right clicking on any page element and clicking 'Inspect'.

I saved your code, opened the file and in the 'Console' tab I see:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

This error is on line 8:

```
var a = new XMLHttpRequest():
```

Either remove this colon, or replace it with a semicolon, and you may be one step closer to fixing your problem.